# Reactjs: How to use a callback passed to this child component to update a parent component's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The child component will add data and the parent component will display the latest data that the child component inserted, my problem is the useState didnt work properly, because the data is successfully saved but i cant see the data inserted in the parent component, need to refresh or load the page to see the latest data.

Parent component

```
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await getDepartment('fmDepartments', 'fmDepartmentsId', 'All', 100, 0);
    console.log(response)
    
    response.data.map(function(u){
   
      newUsers.push({
         sequence:u.sequence,
         name: u.name,
         datecreated: u.datecreated,
         dateupdated: u.dateupdated,
         status: u.status,

         actions: ([
          <div className={classes.root}>
            {u.status !== 1 ?(
            <Tooltip title={<span style={{fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 600,}}>Deactivate</span>} arrow>
              <IconButton 
                  aria-label="Deactivate"
                  color="primary"
                  size="small"
                  className={classes.deactivateButton}
                  onClick={() => {handleActivate(u.id)}}
              >  
              <HighlightOffIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
            ):(
            <Tooltip title={<span style={{fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 600,}}>Activate</span>} arrow>
              <IconButton 
                  aria-label="Active"
                  color="primary"
                  size="small"
                  className={classes.activateButton}
                  onClick={() => {handleDeactivate(u.id)}}
              >  
              <CheckCircleOutlineIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
            )
            } 
          </div>
        ])
      })
    })
    setNewUserLists(newUsers)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [reRender]);


const options = {
    filter: true,
    filterType: 'checkbox',
    selectableRows: 'none',
    print: false,
    customToolbar: () => {
      return (
          <CustomToolbar/> //here is the link to the child component
      )
    },
     setFilterChipProps: (colIndex, colName, data) => {
      return {
        color: 'primary',
        variant: 'outlined',
        className: 'testClass123',
      };
    }
  };
   
  return (
    <>
        <MUIDataTable
          title={"Department"}
          data={newUserLists}
          columns={columns}
          options={options}
        />
    </>
  )
```

child component

```
class CustomToolbar extends React.Component {
 
  constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.HandleAdd = this.HandleAdd.bind(this);
     this.state =false //here
    }
  
  HandleAdd = () => {
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Add Department',
    text: "Input department name below.",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Save',
    html: generateInputForms({
      strname: '',
      intsequence: ''
    }),

    preConfirm: () => {
      let strname = document.getElementById('strname').value;
      let intsequence = document.getElementById('intsequence').value;
 
      if (!strname) {
        Swal.showValidationMessage('The Department field is required.')
      }
      if (!intsequence) {
        Swal.showValidationMessage('The Sequence field is required.')
      }
      return {
        strname: document.getElementById('strname').value,
        intsequence: document.getElementById('intsequence').value
      }
    }
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      let request = {
        strresourcename: "Richard",
        strapplicationcode: "SchoolApp",
        strmodulename: "Department",
        strtablename: "fmDepartments",
        strfieldid: "fmDepartmentsId",
        strname:document.getElementById('strname').value,
        intsequence:document.getElementById('intsequence').value
      }
      addDepartment(request).then(res =>{
        if (res.status == 200){
            Swal.fire({
              icon: 'success',
              title: 'Department',
              text: 'New Department has been added successfully.',
            }).then(res => {
              this.setState(!this.state); //here
            })
        }else{
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Oops',
            text: 'Something went wrong.',
          })
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Tooltip title={"Add"}>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              size="small"
              style={{
                textTransform: 'unset',
                outline: 'none',
                marginLeft: 20,
                backgroundColor: '#00B029',
              }}
              onClick={this.HandleAdd}
              className={classes.button}
              startIcon={<AddIcon className={classes.addIcon} style={{color: '#fff',}} />}
            >
              Add
            </Button>
        </Tooltip>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What state in the parent component is the child component updating? Where is the parent component rendering the child component and what props are being passed? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Which callback function are passing down to child component?

Comment: okay, I will update the parent component

Comment: @RobLjm the callback is im not pretty sure if im doing good on it, i dont know, that is why I am here posting problem to fix my error

Comment: I hope you all understand

Comment: and im not sure or i dont know what im missing. please help!!

Comment: We're asking to see where the parent component renders the `CustomToolbar` child component, and what function you are referring to that is passed to the child as a callback.

Comment: @DrewReese  <CustomToolbar/> //here is the link to the child component

Comment: It doesn't appear as though you pass any props to your toolbar component.

Comment: but how ? i dont know to do that

Comment: Passing props is a React basic: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html